# In Firebase Firestore, how is snapshot `size` different from snapshot.docs `length`?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The definition of [size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#size) under QuerySnapshot says:

```
size
size: number
The number of documents in the QuerySnapshot.
```

[docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) says

```
docs
docs: Array<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>>
An array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot.
```

***As far as Firestore is concerned***, is there an operational difference between doing `let a = snap.docs.length` and doing `let a = snap.size`?

Like for example, will `size` count things that Firestore knows about while the simple `length` of the array does not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two values are exactly the same; both indicate the number of documents in the result set/query snapshot.

Comment: "Google Cloud Employee" - - - Well ok then, I guess that settles that. Thanks for your *snappy*  response.